# Why is Movable Type suffixing my stylesheet?

Tags: movabletype

I am trying to restore a blog running a... vintage version of Movable Type (4.25). I'm running into an issue where the index stylesheet template isn't loaded whenever I load a page. The browser gets a 500 trying to access `styles-site.css`, which I don't blame it for, since the web root does not contain a `styles-site.css`. It does, however, contain a `styles-site.css.static`, and when I rename it to `styles-site.css`, the page works fine.

[This is the configuration for the template that is (I believe) generating the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9tNW.png) As you can see, publishing is set to static, and the output file is `styles-site.css`. Yet, when I publish, it will put the content instead in `styles-site.css.static`, and nothing will be able to find it. Also, the View Published Template link to the right is a link to `styles-site.css`, so even Movable Type seems convinced that the file should be there. And yet... It doesn't generate it there. It generates `styles-site.css.static`, and if I rename that to remove the static, the site will work until I republish, at which point `styles-site.css` will be removed and `styles-site.css.static` will be put back.

Any ideas on what's causing this or if there's a setting I can tweak? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Self-resolved:

I snooped around the MT code for something that appends `.static` to a string, and found something in `WeblogPublisher.pm`. It appends `.static` to filenames a couple times, but both of them check to see if the thing being published that they deal with is being statically or dynamically published. I thought this was bizarre because I specifically statically published this stylesheet.

I fired up phpMyAdmin and looked at the templates table. The dynamic flag was enabled for the stylesheet template, so I set it to zero and republished. Stylesheet is present!